# Ошибка при сохранении объекта Django: value too long for type character varying(40)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Имеется Django-приложение, задеплоенное на продуктив. Всё настроено нормально, nginx через proxy_pass шлёт всё на gunicorn. Проблема следующая: при сохранении некоторых объектов в админке падает Server error(500), причем ошибка не nginx-овская. По полям есть ограничения, но они соблюдены, продиагностировать не удаётся.

Код валидный, без подводных камней и на dev-сервере отрабатывает корректно.

Откопали логи, в результате чего ошибка

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/website/banner/1/change/

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(40)
```

Но вся проблема в том, что в CharField max_length указан 40, а в поле вводится значение 21 символ, но на русском языке.

Comment: В логах всё должно быть написано

Comment: В nginx всё нормально, есть запись о 500, но точно не он отработал, а по gunicorn логов нет.

Comment: «по gunicorn логов нет» — значит пришло время их настроить

Comment: Я сейчас спрашиваю, потому что времени настраивать логи нет, это продуктив и проект не мой. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобным поведением и поделится решением. Откуда вы такие берётесь? "В логах всё есть" - дак знаем, что есть. Наверное, перед вопросом уже о них подумали, как вы считаете.

Comment: Без логов помогут только телепаты — сомневаюсь, что здесь такие водятся

Comment: Я ещё раз повторяю, возможно кто-то сталкивался с таким поведением - тот сможет подсказать. Нет - сделаем логи и сами на свой вопрос ответим. Не нужно быть телепатом, чтобы узнать знакомую ситуацию.

Comment: Логи с gunicorn ничего не показали, сделали допом ещё на Django и в них выявилась ошибка. Добавил к вопросу.

Comment: Ну наконец-то. В кодировке utf-8 21 русский символ это 42 байта, так что начинаю подозревать какие-то проблемы с кодировкой или в базе, или в джанге, или везде сразу

Comment: Напишите ответ, а не коммент, помечу как решение.

Comment: Это не решение, потому что я не являюсь специалистом по постгресу и не знаю, чем конкретно это может быть вызвано и как это исправить. В документации написано, что varying(40) означает именно 40 символов, а не 40 байт, а значит 21 русский символ по-хорошему должен влезать. Почему не влезают — не знаю. Может, спецы по постгресу ещё заглянут и что-нибудь напишут

Comment: В любом случае - помогло.